# How to register slash commands automaically when bot enters server discord.js

Tags: discord.js

As of now i have my bot manually deploy slash commands to the server. What should i do so that the bot self registers the slash commands without using a prefix command/registers itself as soon as it enters a server. Here's the code i'm using as of now for deploying slash commands. I'm using discord.js V13 btw

```
if(content === "!deploy guild") {
            if(!message.guild) return;

            console.log("Deploying commands in guild...");

            await message.guild.commands.set(commands).then(() => console.log(`Commands deployed in guild ${message.guild.name}!`));

            await message.reply("Deployed in guild!");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be looking at the **[`Events#GuildCreate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/typedef/Events)** emitter, once there is a new guild the bot is added to, this event is fired ( emitted )  and you can add your commands / do any specific task you wish to do on joining a new guild

Setting up a listener for it with your `client` your code would look something like so:

```js
/*
* client is your discord.js Client
* commands obj is your command data you want to add to the guild
*/
client.on('guildCreate', async (guild) => {
guild.commands.set(commands).then(() => 
console.log(`Commands deployed in guild ${guild.name}!`));
})
```